# How to create a global resource file for a WinForm application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to use same resource file for different projects.

My resource file name is named Resource1.resx 
and  I created a .resources extension file by using resgen and I generated a .resources.dll by using al.exe

But then as I try to use the file in my project, I am getting one error, my code is something similar to this:

```
ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager("Resource1",
                              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string msg = resmgr.GetString("name");
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

The error message is something like this:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resource1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WinTest" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You are loading the Resources from the Executing Assembly but as you mentioned you have defined the resources in a separate assembly.

Instead of the executing assembly you should point it to your resources dll.

Comment: yes i created the resource file in the same executing assembly. and created the .resources.dll file. is it necessary to make it a separate project and create a resource dll file.?

Comment: I don't completely understand you. You say you have the resources both in the executing assembly and in a seperate resources.dll?

Comment: ys i got it. i created the resource file inside one of my project. means i have two projects like project1 and project2, inside the project1 i created the resource file. i think i need to separate the resource file into a new project and compile. thank you.